# Owl Carousel cutting div

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have a little problem. I using OwlCarousel 2 to make 'testimonial rotator/slider', but it looks like that:
[image]

But I need somethink like this - the image is cutted on top:
[image]

I packed 'box' in one more div, but it's not fix it.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="testimonial-box">
        <div class="testimonial-content">
            <div class="testimonial-logo">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-left" />
            </div>
            <p>
                <!-- CONTENT -->
            </p>
            <div class="testimonial-meta">
                <p>
                    <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                    <span>, <i>Web Developer</i></span>
                </p>
                <p class="website">
                    <a href="http://vrs-factory.pl">VRS-Factory</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS [SASS]:

```
section.testimonials {
        padding: 30px 0;

        .testimonial-logo {
            img {
                margin-top: -88px;
            }
        }

        .testimonial-content {
            border: 1px solid rgba( $SecondColor, .2 );
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .testimonial-meta {
            h5 {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
        }

        .owl-carousel {
            .owl-item {
                img {
                    width: auto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is demo: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/vertisan/pen/wGmNvQ)

Comment: Can you please share some JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net) to reproduce the issue please ? The code you provide isn't exactly the same as your issue.

Comment: @VincentG Sure, I added link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the `overflow: hidden` of `.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer`.

I add a `margin-top` on `.owl-item` to fix it.

```
.owl-item { margin-top: 70px; }
```

[Live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGmNBR)